# Check if object is an sqlalchemy model instance

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to know how to know, given an object, if it is an instance of an sqlalchemy mapped model.

Normally, I would use isinstance(obj, DeclarativeBase). However, in this scenario, I do not have the DeclarativeBase class used available (since it is in a dependency project).

I would like to know what is the best practice in this case.

```
class Person(DeclarativeBase):
      __tablename__ = "Persons"

p = Person()

print isinstance(p, DeclarativeBase)
#prints True

#However in my scenario, I do not have the DeclarativeBase available
#since the DeclarativeBase will be constructed in the depending web app
#while my code will act as a library that will be imported into the web app
#what are my alternatives?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [class_mapper()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=class_mapper#sqlalchemy.orm.class_mapper) and catch the exception.
Or you could use `_is_mapped_class`, but ideally you should not as it is not a public method.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import class_mapper
def _is_sa_mapped(cls):
    try:
        class_mapper(cls)
        return True
    except:
        return False
print _is_sa_mapped(MyClass)
    
# @note: use this at your own risk as might be removed/renamed in the future
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import _is_mapped_class
print bool(_is_mapped_class(MyClass))
```

Comment: Thanks van. My original question was about the object instance not the class. Do I change your code to an object_mapper instead?

Comment: You can always get the class of an instance; `type(instance)`

Comment: Sure, you can use the object_mapper. Or as indicated above, just get the type. Up to you...

Answer (score 3):

for instances there is the `object_mapper()`, so:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.base import object_mapper

def is_mapped(obj):
    try:
        object_mapper(obj)
    except UnmappedInstanceError:
        return False
    return True
```

the complete mapper utilities are documented here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_api.html

Just a consideration: since specific errors are raised by SQLAlchemy (`UnmappedClassError` for calsses and `UnmappedInstanceError` for instances) why not catch them rather than a generic exception? ;)